# Reference conforming class type in protocol

Tags: swift

given a protocol `Conforming`, how would I write a function with is able to infer the type of the class conforming to it.

```swift
protocol Conforming<T> {
    associatedtype T
    func returnSelf() -> T // For example
}

class Test: Conforming {
    typealias T = Test
    
    func returnSelf() -> Test {
        return self
    }

}
```

This is quite messy, having to declare the `typealias` in every conforming object. Is there a way with generics to have `returnSelf()` infer the return type with generics?

Such that things would like this in each class

```swift
class Test: Conforming {
    
    func returnSelf() -> Test { //Automatically synthesised the return type
        return self
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following seems to give the result you want without the need to use generics.

```
protocol Conforming {
    func returnSelf() -> Self // For example
}

class Test: Conforming {
    func returnSelf() -> Self {
        return self
    }
}
```

As a test, the following gives the correct results:

```
let t = Test()
let s = t.returnSelf()
print(type(of: t), type(of: s))
```

Output:

> Test Test

It even works if you extend `Test`:

```
class More: Test {
}

let m = More()
let n = m.returnSelf()
print(type(of: m), type(of: n))
```

Output:

> More More